# Runtime Error '13' Type Mismatch in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I am working on a code project in which I need to match a value from one cell in column G in one sheet (in this case 'test sheet') to a value from a cell in column B in another sheet (in this case 'Information'). Once I have found this matching row in the 'Information' sheet, I need to retrieve the integer value from column C in that matching row.

I am trying to implement this code in a function that I could call from a different part of my program. I have tried dimensioning my variables in many different ways, but I am stuck with a type mismatch that occurs when I call my function from my main sub. I am very lost and frustrated. Can any of you see what I am doing incorrectly?

The main sub call:

```
Sub AutoSend()
    Dim Temp As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim r As Range

    Set rng = Range("A2:I6")

    For Each r in rng.Rows 'EDIT to more accurately reflect my code
        Temp = FindHigh(Cells(r,7).Value) 'THROWS ERROR HERE
    Next r
End Sub
```

The function FindHigh that is called:

```
Function FindHigh(Key As String) As Integer

    Dim Target
    Dim Success As Integer

    Success = 0

    Sheets("Information").Select

    Set Target = Columns(2).Find(Key, LookIn:=xlValues)

    If Not Target Is Nothing Then
        Sheets("Information").Cells(Target.row, 3).Select
        Success = Rows(Target.RowIndex).Cells(Target.RowIndex, 3).Value
    End If

    Sheets("Test Sheet").Select
    FindHigh = Success

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it should be `Temp = FindHigh(Range("R7").Value)`

Or `Temp = FindHigh(Cells(7,18))`

Comment: Ahhh I figured out my problem! I should have written `r.Cells(1,7)` instead of `Cells(r,7)` Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your Sub "AutoSend" you are using 'r' that hasn't been defined anywhere

Comment: Oops I'm sorry about that. I left out some of my code to make it simpler to analyze. The r comes from a loop. I will edit my original post appropriately. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could give this a try.

```
Sub AutoSend()
    Dim Temp As Integer
    Dim r As Integer
    r = 1 'Row Number of the Row in column G that has the value you want to look up.  
    With WorksheetFunction
    Temp = .IfError(.VLookup(Sheets("Test Sheet").Cells(r, 7).Value, _
                    Sheets("Information").Range("B:C"), 2, False), 0)
    End With
End Sub
```

If the cell that has the value you are looking for is ***NOT*** in column G, or comes from a loop telling us what cell holds the value you would like to look up, OR giving us the code to your loop would be very helpful in giving you a better answer.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you! I am getting an error when I implement this code. The error is as follows: unable to get the vlookup property of the worksheetfunction class. Do you know why I am getting this message?

Comment: All figured out! I had the wrong worksheet selected! Thank you for all of your help!